# Проблема с библиотекой translate

Tags: python

Код:

```
from translate import Translator
translator= Translator(from_lang="russian", to_lang="english")
translation = translator.translate("Привет Андрей")
input(translation)
```

Он должен 'Привет Андрей' с русского перевести на английский.
И выводит он: "Приветствую!"

Для тех кто будет писать "input() на print() замени" проверю, напишу,  как проверю.

UPD: Как не странно не чего не изменилось)

Comment: Библиотека абсолютно ни при чём, что ей переводчик выдал, то она и вывела https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lWlh.png

Comment: А пофиксить не как? Там библиотека мб есть ещё какая то?

Comment: _кто будет писать "input() на print() замени_ — я буду. А что куда должно выводится, если принта нет? Ну, серьёзно?

Comment: Вы приколист? input() выводит точно так же как и print() только не чего не будет дальше происходить пока что то не введёшь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться другой библиотекой, например [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/4.0.0rc1/)

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
```

Пример использования:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate('Привет, Андрей', dest='en')

print(result.text)
```

Вывод:

```
>> Hi Andrew
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручили